# Django Page Restriction (Admin and Members could be able to see it)

Tags: python, django

Thanks for your help

I got a question :

I want to make accessible only for two type of people: admin (ForeignKey) and friends (ManyToMany). All belongs to the same model.

**The issue is user who belongs to `friends` are redirected to '/' and can not see the page**

self.object.user -> `user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)`
self.object.friends -> `friends = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True,related_name='friends_reservation')`

```
def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if not (request.user == self.object.user or request.user == self.object.friends):
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Edit :

```
def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
            self.object = self.get_object()
            if not (request.user == self.object.user or request.user in self.object.friends):
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

**issue:**

argument of type 'ManyRelatedManager' is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a change :)

```
def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if not (request.user == self.object.user or request.user in self.object.friends.all()):
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the user is within the current `friends` instance.

But you should see if what you have in `self.object.friends` is a queryset or not. Querysets are collections, so you can use `in` to check if an item belongs to it. Also, just to be careful, let's remove those parens:

```
def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if not request.user == self.object.user or request.user not in self.object.friends:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer yes I'm doing a test so the user that I try is in the instance... with your I got an issue: argument of type 'ManyRelatedManager' is not iterable